# What to do with bad answer?

Tags: discussion

once again, I've failed my "understand RPG.SE rules" roll. Can anyone help me figure out what to do with [this answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/11318/696)?

I would like to edit it to improve it, but the "bad" part has already generated all the comments. Do I edit it to improve, delete it, or leave the bad part as an "antipattern" for others to learn from?

Answer (score 9):

Not sure what you mean. The comments will get deleted eventually; improve your answer to include info from them if you like...

I guess the answer is "edit to improve.". The comments will be deleted. Or delete your answer if it's unsalvageable.  We don't leave wrong junk to be instructive (I think everyone knows there's an infinite number of ways to have bad answers, and have no need to be instructed in the art of it...)

Comment: Addendum: If you feel you've answered/obsoleted a comment and don't want it around anymore, you can always flag it for moderator attention.